# Calculate result according to previous item in the list result

Tags: python, for-in-loop

I´m running into some trouble making a calculation over a list of numbers. The initial list corresponds to temperature data and I need to calculate the RunningMean temperature each day. The Running Mean for each day depends on the previous day´s running mean as well as the previous day´s temperature (and a constant).

Considering that I have a list with the Temperature, I´m defining the list RunningMean as a copy, and then replacing each item according to the formula.

```
Temperature = [14.5, 13, 15, 16]
RunningMean = Temperature
RMConstant = 0.8
for i in RunningMean [1:3]:         
    RunningMean [i] = (1-RMConstant)*Temperature[i-1]+RMConstant*RMean[i-1]
#I skip the first item to avoid problems when calling i-1 index
#Replace each item in RunningMean with the result of the formula
```

For some reason, the iteration at line 5 is giving me the following error: 
 *expected index value, got float*

Any ideas of what is going wrong? Probably it is a basic mistake, but I´ve been scratching my head for a couple of days already.

Many thanks!

Comment: `i` is not an index. It is one of the values from the `RunningMean [1:3]` slice (a list with two integers in it).

Comment: I think you should use range(1, 3) instead RunningMean [1:3] in for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Temperature = [14.5, 13, 15, 16]
RunningMean = Temperature
RMConstant = 0.8
for i in range(1,len(RunningMean)):
    RunningMean [i] = (1-RMConstant)*Temperature[i-1]+RMConstant*RunningMean[i-1]
```

I didn't know what `RMean` was so I used `RunningMean` instead to see results while trying it.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand a bit better how for-in loops work. `RMean` was my previous short name, forgot to replace it for clarification. You´re right, same as `RunningMean`

However, now the output of `RunninMean` is 14.5 repeatedly, for all the items in the list. Do you know why I could be getting `[14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5]` as an output?

Comment: I found the problem: by doing `RunningMean = Temperature`, once you change `RunningMean` in your loop so is `Temperature` because this is how lists work. Instead you should `import copy` and use `RunningMean = copy.copy(Temperature)`. Cheers mate.

Comment: Ahhh, there it was! Now it's running perfect. `RunningMean` is used to calculate the Adaptive comfort band according to the standard EN15251. It is mostly used for buildings running passively (not heated nor cooled during certain periods).
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code, `RunningMean [1:3]` returns `[13, 15]` which is sliced version of `RunningMean`.

What you should do is instead of `RunningMean[1:3]` in the for loop, replace it with `range(1,len(RunningMean))`. It will give you the desired result.